# Chrome, table columns don't align after editing row with jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, html-table

I've cleared a row and then added new cells using jQuery.  This works fine in Firefox, but the columns don't align correctly in google Chrome.  I've included a picture that uses Google Chrome's debugger to demonstrate what I'm talking about:

[image]

And this is the code:

```
// clear old contents
row.empty();
row.inputs={};
// write new cells
for( var i=0; i<this.fields.length; i++){
    var field = this.fields[i];
    var newCell = $('<td></td>');
    row.append(newCell);
    var newInput = $('<input></input>');
    newCell.append(newInput);
    row.inputs[field.name] = newInput;
    newInput.val(row.representedObject[field.name]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Removes not only the markup but the DOM reference as well. Might solve your problem, as well as any possible problems related to the DOM.